# How to change GET parameters on the click of a button, using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Apologies if I am not supplying enough information here or not making any sense, please let me know if I need to edit the question.

I have a URL with a parameter that I'm after changing on the click of a button as part of pagination for 
a small CMS. For example, I want it so the following url:

```
www.example.com/page=1
```

When I click a button, I want it to change to the next following URL. However, I don't want the page to refresh.

```
www.example.com/page=2
```

I'm guessing this uses ajax and javascript/jQuery, but I haven't had any luck in finding a simple method that I can understand.

Comment: The URLs appear to be the same?

Comment: They are. Let me change that!

Comment: That makes more sense :) Use pushState: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState. However you will need to write you own logic to deal with reading and updating the content based on that URL value (if necessary)

Comment: You want to change only url or also load content without page reload?

Comment: @Andris — It wouldn't be very useful pagination if the content didn't change!

Comment: Then depends where are you creating. If some framework, follow its guidelines, if some website, where only some part needs to paginated you can implement ajax etc.

Comment: @GetALife here is a pagination example with ajax [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/robazedera/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can.

When the server receives a Request by either GET or POST,it may run a program, passing the query string, which in this case is the URL + what ever GET parameter you gave it, and return what ever it needs to return to the client.

Going to the url "www.index.html" is sending a GET request to the server via get for the document "index.html".

If you change the URL in any way, by clicking a link, or using "document.location" in Js etc, the server will get called, and return to you the web page corresponding to that URL assuming its possible.

You can however as you suggested send those parameters to the server using ajax without reloading the page. But if you change the URL, you are by definition reloading the page. 
With ajax the operation also happen on the server side, but this time it doesn't returns you the web page, only whatever data the URL you specified returns, hence your browser does not reload.

Try the following code(you'll have to make a "something.php" file) :

```
    <body>
        <button type="button">The button</button>
        <p>Ajax stuff</p>
    </body>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(e){
            var url = document.location
            console.log(url);

            $("button").click(function(){
                document.location = document.location + "?name=2"
                console.log(url);
                console.log("The button was clicked");
            });

            $("p").click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: "something.php",
                    method: "GET",
                    success: function(){
                        console.log("The ajax funciton executed")
                    }
                });
            });
    });
    </script>
```

If you look at the console you'll notice that whenever you click the button, and change the url everything is reloaded and you don't see the previous console logs.

But click the p element as many time as you want the page is not reloaded and you can still see the other console logs.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for this, I did fear that might be the case. I have a reporting system that displays the results table using ajax so there's no reloading the page, but it's the pagination I'm struggling with. It either displays a certain amount of data which you select, or all of it. I'll take a look into your answer in a bit and I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: " but it's the pagination I'm struggling with. It either displays a certain amount of data which you select, or all of it. I'll take a look into your answer in a bit and I'll let you know how it goes. "

Maybe you could extract from the return data of your ajax Function ? 

If you could it would make it easier to see the relevant parts of your HTML/JS and what ever back-end language you're using. 

Good luck.